# How to query all all objects through 2 levels of has_many in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to query all objects that are related to an object through 2 layers of has_many relationship.

Suppose we have the following sort of hierarchy: Blog has_many Posts which has_many Comments. Then I want all Comments which are related to a Blog.

In my example we have:

```rb
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
end
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :blog
  has_many :comments
end
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :posts
end
```

And I want a relation of all Comments's for a given Blog. Right now, I'm double querying

```rb
blog = Blog.find(2) # some block instance
Comment.where(post_id: [blog.posts.pluck(:id)])
```

There's gotta be a better way :)

Comment: `pluck` is only needed when you actually want an array of the just the plucked columns (read: almost never) and you don't need to wrap it in yet another array. If you just write `Comment.where(post_id: blog.posts)` ActiveRecord will actually create a subquery. But this should be done through indirect assocations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new `has_many :through` association:

```rb
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments, through: :posts
end
```

Then, you will be able to:

```rb
blog = Blog.find(2)
blog.comments
```

Also, you can now preload (`includes` and friends) records via Active Record API.

Further documentation: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association.